# How to configure grunt to not ignore any path

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-wiredep, wiredep

The grunt-wiredep task is removing `../` from all paths.

For example:

```
../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
```

becomes

```
bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
```

I want `../` to be maintained. But if I set `ignorePath` to blank string (one space character) or remove the  `ignorePath` parameter, no javascript files are included in HTML.